# Assigning resource create location policy to subscriptions when other policy denied at tenant root level

Tags: azure, azure-policy

We are in a situation to allow WestUS region in Azure policy for resource creation but there is other Azure policy assigned at tenant root level which allows only "North Europe"and "West Europe".

can you please help us how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an exclusion/notScope to the resource scope. Here is documentation on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/assignment-structure#excluded-scopes